# radius of convergence of number of divisors

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

i am stuck on this question for a while and i'm not sure about it

i need to calculate the radius of convergence for: $\sum _{n=1}^\infty d(n)x^n$

what i did:

since i cannot use the root test or check the next eleent against its previous(ratio test), i think that to find the radius of convergence i need to check for the upper limit(sup).

so what i did is this: if n=1 we get that its one, so while going to a very large n, i think that $d(n) < n$. if this is correct, then tha radius should be: $\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n \to \infty}d(n) ^ {\frac{1}{n}}$. however, i don't know how to calculate it.

am i correct? how can i calculate the radius of convergence here?

Comment: oh, they're showing it in a way easier way. i'm wondering: is my way is bad? if not, can anyon show me how to solve it the way i showed?

Comment: You started with $d(n) < n$, which is good. The answer to the "possible duplicate" shows how to continue.